# Swapping an input image on hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, hover

I am using an image for an input (button) within a form on my website, and would like to swap the image on hover.

The following code works fine in a stand alone demo. The images swap nicely.

However... when I integrate this code into the rest of the form code, it fails.

I am guessing it is because the script calls for `getElementsByTagName('input')` with the tag name being `input`.

Therefore... perhaps because the form contains other 'inputs', the function targets the other inputs as well, and simply dies??????

Is there a way to execute this same function, and target the specific input without using the `getElementsByTagName('input')`, or by tweaking it some way?

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
  input = inputs[i];
  input.onmouseover = function() {
    this.setAttribute('data-orig-image', this.getAttribute('src'));
    this.src = this.getAttribute('data-alt-image');
  };
  input.onmouseout = function() {
    this.src = this.getAttribute('data-orig-image');
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="image" src="/images/image1.png" data-alt-image="/images/image2.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `querySelectorAll`, then you can use CSS selectors - this way, you can narrow down your list however you like (limit is CSS selectors only).

In the snippet below I broke up your code a bit, but the main point (regarding your question) is that with `querySelectorAll` I could narrow down the `input` list with a `type`. This way, if really a clash is the problem in your context, the problem should be solved (of course, you could be adding a `class`, or just "filter" for the `data-alt-image`).

Also, by updating the iterator function (`for...i++` -> `inputs.forEach`), it works nicely with multiple inputs.

```js
const ORIG_URL_ATTR = 'src'
const ALT_URL_ATTR = 'data-alt-image'

const switchImageUrls = ([curr, alt]) => [alt, curr]

const getImageUrls = (input) => [input.getAttribute(ORIG_URL_ATTR), input.getAttribute(ALT_URL_ATTR)]

const setImageUrls = (input) => ([curr, alt]) => {
  input.setAttribute(ORIG_URL_ATTR, curr)
  input.setAttribute(ALT_URL_ATTR, alt)
}

const handleMouseEvent = (input) => {
  setImageUrls(input)(switchImageUrls(getImageUrls(input)))
}

const setEventHandlers = (input) => {
  input.onmouseover = () => handleMouseEvent(input);
  input.onmouseout = () => handleMouseEvent(input);
}

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="image"]');

inputs.forEach(setEventHandlers)
```

```html
<input type="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=orig1" data-alt-image="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=alt1" />
<input type="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=orig2" data-alt-image="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=alt2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple if you use data attributes; set up the original with `swapper.dataset.origImage = swapper.getAttribute('src');` (or put that in the HTML originally as data attributes) then just swap them on the mouse events

```js
let swappers = document.querySelectorAll('.image-swapper');
swappers.forEach((swapper) => {
  swapper.dataset.origImage = swapper.getAttribute('src');
  swapper.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.src = event.currentTarget.dataset.altImage;
  });
  swapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
    event.currentTarget.src = event.currentTarget.dataset.origImage;
  });
});
```

```css
.image-swapper {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<input class="image-swapper" type="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" data-alt-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg" />
<input class="image-swapper" type="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg" data-alt-image="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You specified JavaScript and jQuery, so here is a short & sweet jQuery solution:

```js
function swapImage(elem) {
  let src = elem.attr('src');
  let alt = elem.data('alt');
  elem.attr('src', alt);
  elem.data('alt', src);
}

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('input[type="image"]').hover(function () {
    swapImage($(this));
  }, function () {
    swapImage($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=orig1" data-alt="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=alt1" />
<input type="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/808080?text=orig2" data-alt="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=alt2" />
```

Explanation:

- the image has `src` and `data-alt` attributes
- the jQuery `.hover()` function has two callbacks, one for entering, one for leaving
- on both hover callbacks we call the `swapImage()` function, which swaps the values of the `src` and a `data-alt` attributes

Comment: I did not down vote you however you probably should use the mouse events .`on('mouseenter', function()` mouseleave etc. and `$('document').ready(function() {` can just be the recommended `$('function() {`